# Remove additional parameters from Youtube link

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a function that converts Youtube links into linked youtube thumbnail. I also need to remove additional parameters from Youtube links, for example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pIaI93YGY&list=RD9_pIaI93YGY&start_radio=1
```

needs to be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pIaI93YGY
```

This my code:

```
$message = 'text text text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pIaI93YGY text text text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PUT2a5NafI&list=RD1PUT2a5NafI&start_radio=1 more text more text';

$reg_exUrl_youtube = "/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'> \r\n]+)(?![^<]*>)/";

$message = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl_youtube, function($matches) {
return "<div class=\"videoss videoss{$matches[1]}\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"videoshow\" id=\"{$matches[1]}\"><div style=\"background:url(/i/play.png) center no-repeat,url([zzzzz]img.youtube.com/vi/{$matches[1]}/mqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:30%,cover;\" class=\"pd39 mroim60\"></div></a></div>";
}, $message);
```

But the result is as you can see in the image below. Additional parameters are not being removed and displayed as text:

[image]

So, how do I remove all additional parameters from Youtube links?

Comment: Where is the `$reg_exUrl_youtube`? Did you try a pattern?

Comment: Forgot to post. Just added.

Comment: Your pattern matches what you are looking for https://regex101.com/r/4wsVOm/1 What you do want to replace and what is `$message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your pattern you could match all after the capturing group using 0+ times a non whitespace char `\S*` so that it will not be in the replacement string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzAiP6/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/l5Z3c)

The id is in group 1 and you can create your custom replacement using `$matches[1]`

There can be a few optimizations for your pattern. If you use a different delimiter than `/` like `~`, you don't have to escape the forward slashes.

These constructs `(?:i)?` can be simplified to `i?` and you don't have to escape the `?` and `"` in the character class. If you don't want to match a space or newline, perhaps matching `\s` in the negated character class could be shorter.

For example

```
$reg_exUrl_youtube = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?vi?=|(?:embed|vi?|user)/))([^?&"\'>\s]+)(?![^<]*>)\S*~';
$message = 'text text text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pIaI93YGY text text text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PUT2a5NafI&list=RD1PUT2a5NafI&start_radio=1 more text more text';

$message = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl_youtube, function($matches) {
    return "<div class=\"videoss videoss{$matches[1]}\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"videoshow\" id=\"{$matches[1]}\"><div style=\"background:url(/i/play.png) center no-repeat,url([zzzzz]img.youtube.com/vi/{$matches[1]}/mqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:30%,cover;\" class=\"pd39 mroim60\"></div></a></div>";
}, $message);

echo $message;
```

Comment: Your answer just removes additional parameters from Youtube links. But I also need to convert them into thumbnails with links to Youtube videos: 

`return "<div class=\"videoss videoss{$matches[1]}\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"videoshow\" id=\"{$matches[1]}\"><div style=\"background:url(/i/play.png) center no-repeat,url([zzzzz]img.youtube.com/vi/{$matches[1]}/mqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:30%,cover;\" class=\"pd39 mroim60\"></div></a></div>`

Comment: That is correct, you have the right url so you could use that string and use `$matches[1]` where you want. See https://3v4l.org/HLXbG using your string.

Comment: `$matches[1]` should be only video ID, for example `9_pIaI93YGY` and not `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pIaI93YGY`. My code does everything correctly, but problem is that it leaves all aditional parameters as a part of text. For example, if I had text `text text text`, the result is Youtube thumbnail and text `&list=RD1PUT2a5NafI&start_radio=1 text text text`